# Detect which child control received a Pointer* event

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have a container control that is handling PointerPressed and PointerMoved events.

The container contains a set of buttons.

At the point of handling the event, how can I determine which button actually received it?

```
    mainPage.AddHandler(PointerPressedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(pointerPressedHandler), true);        
    private void pointerPressedHandler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.GetCurrentPoint(null); // maybe can be done using position info?
        var s = e.OriginalSource as Border; // OriginalSource is a Border, not the Button, and I don't seem to be able to get to the Button from the Border

        // todo - determine which button was clicked
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
    private void pointerPressedHandler(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.GetCurrentPoint(null);
        var elements = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(p.Position, mainPage, false);

        Button foundButton;
        foreach (var item in elements)
        {
            foundButton = item as Button;
            if (foundButton != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("found button: " + foundButton.Name);
            }
        }
    }
```